# The [refactor-my-code] tag: should it be nuked?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [refactor-my-code](/questions/tagged/refactor-my-code) tag seems pretty worthless. With 156 questions tagged with it as of this writing, it's certainly not small enough to destroy with no consideration, but the mere matter it covers seems to fall into the off-topic range for Stack Overflow.

These questions seem to be essentially suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a straight-up meta-tag to me; you don't need a tag to ask folks to look at your code. There's [refactor](/questions/tagged/refactor) for questions *about* refactoring.

Burninated.

Answer (score 3):

My initial reaction:  That tag **exists?!**

Some reasons for burnination:

- Code review isn't something SO does specifically; it is like you said, better suited for Code Review.  Hopefully they're *high quality* code refactoring questions, and not just a literal "refactor this plz" request.
- One could argue that it's beneficial; I mean, you learn a bit about how to refactor code, but it's only for that specific code base.  Not just that, but there are books and tutorials out there on the subject as well.

Some reasons against burnination:

- If one wants to ask pointed questions on how to refactor a *specific* piece of code, I wouldn't mind that *as much*.
- If the question is in regards as to *why* a specific refactoring is appropriate, I don't mind that as much either.

It would take some looking to dive through this; it's not easy to take a <del>sledgehammer</del> fire-breathing dragon-like thing to this tag until the questions are considered for migration, survival or closure.

Comment: Exactly my opinion. I'd like to point out, though, that the reasons to keep the tag can both be rebuffed by pointing out that we *already have a refactoring tag*. This tag seems rather... pointless considering that it can only mean "ZOMG refactor this code pl0x, kthxbie".